# Pocket Pc, Smart phone

Tags: pocketpc, smartphone

I am new in Pocket PC and Smart phone. so can any one help me out regarding following queries.
Which SDK used for Pocket PC and Smart Phone?
Can we use web service in that application or Can we call from the Pocket PC application?
and can we integrate third party application in our Pocket PC application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pocket PCs are devices that run Microsoft Windows Mobile. Recently they have been integrated with phones making them a smartphone. Smartphones are any PDA + Phones, but they do no necessarily have to run windows mobile, the most popular smartphones do not (iPhone, Blackberry)

[Windows Mobile 6 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=06111A3A-A651-4745-88EF-3D48091A390B&displaylang=en)

With windows mobile, you can run a light version of .NET called .NET Compact Framework, which does allow web service calls. I am not sure about iPhone and Blackberry development but due to some of the applications that I have used will lead me to assume that it will support web services.

As for the third party applications, it depends on what the application does and if it supports Pocket PC development. But other then the compact framework requirement it behaves a lot like a normal Windows Form.

Comment: thanks Adam its very usefull information for me.
thanks a lot.